# What functions should a generic SCC API have?

Tags: api, version-control, labview

I am planning on developing a generic version control API in LabVIEW.
This API should be generic and collable by other tools (LabVIEW IDE, build tools etc.) and give access to different kinds of SCC types (subversion, VCS, Mercurial and GIT) for starters.
My basic question is not how to develop such a tool, but more what functions should be available in this API, or is there some documentation on similar projects in different languages?
Currently I am thinking about the following functions:

- Add file
- Remove file
- Lock file
- Update file
- Get latest revision
- Label current revision
- Export repository
- Push to remote repository
- Get specific revision

What basic functionality am I completely missing?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SCC API is a good place to start. I used to work on a product that now is a part of Oracle portfolio and we used MS SCC API to integrate with a number of source control systems. At the time signing an NDA was required to get the specs, but now I believe it is published on MSDN.

Comment: LabVIEW allready provides an interface to the MS SCC API complient version control systems, it lacks however open sourceness and basic configuration options. And it cannot be used outside it's scope.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SCC API is just an API specs. Whether the source code control system or its SCC API open source or not is up to its vendor, not Microsoft. There are SCC API implementations available for the open source SCCs, for example Subversion: http://www.pushok.com/soft_svn.php .

Answer (score 0):

I regularly use
- archive project 
- set file back to revision x
 - show revision history 
 - merge / diff (-> http://www.dmcinfo.com/blog.aspx/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/136/Using-LVmerge-LabVIEW-Merge-Tool-with-TortoiseSVN.aspx ).
 - undo checkin/update
 - branch

Also, I need folders or something like that.